# Can SDK for iOS allow for user to Login when Offline?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, offline

Is this scenario possible using the Salesforce SDK for iOS?

1. User logs in while online, data sync occurs, user works with app.
2. User logs out
3. User wants to log back in when offline.

Is it possible to set up the authentication in such a way that it allows to login without re-authenticating against Salesforce?

Comment: I am facing same issue , Please let me know if you got any solution of above issue

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to use Salesforce authentication while offline so if you want to secure access to offline data you'll need to roll your own. One method might be to get the user to enter a PIN number after they've logged in the first time online, and then use that to allow or deny access to data in the app when they're offline.